# Undefined property: stdClass::$Blanch

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I Am getting this error

> (Undefined property: stdClass::$Blanch)

While trying to call the relation data in blade `{{$req->Blanch->name}}`

I have created the function in model

```php
public function Blanch()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Blanch::class, 'branch_id', 'id');
}
```

I dont know what is missing anyone with idea can help

```
$req= DB::table('fuel_requests')
        ->LeftJoin('pumps','fuel_requests.pump_id','=','pumps.id')
        ->LeftJoin('cars','fuel_requests.car_id','=','cars.id')
        ->select('fuel_requests.*')
        ->get();
```

while in my model i have

```
protected $table = "fuel_requests"; 
protected $fillable = ['type', 'branch_id', 'car_id', 'pump_id','quantity', 'user_id', 'name', 'deadline', 'verified_by', 'approved_by', 'supplied_by', 'received_by', 'status'];
```

Comment: Can you show us the controller code which sets `$req` and pass it to view

Comment: $req=DB::table('fuel_requests')
                ->LeftJoin('pumps','fuel_requests.pump_id','=','pumps.id')
                ->LeftJoin('cars','fuel_requests.car_id','=','cars.id')
                ->select('fuel_requests.*')->get();

Comment: while in my model i have  //
    protected $table = "fuel_requests";
    protected $fillable = ['type', 'branch_id', 'car_id', 'pump_id','quantity', 'user_id', 'name', 'deadline', 'verified_by', 'approved_by', 'supplied_by', 'received_by', 'status'];

Comment: Can you add these details in your question instead of adding in comments

Comment: Also if you are not selecting any column from pumps and cars then why you are doing left join with these tables , it looks unnecessary

Comment: Actually, I added them just for selecting them through Join after stacking on calling the relation through Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting for undefined property because you are not loading eloquent relation `Blanch`, try using `with()` on `FuelRequest` model

```
$req  = FuelRequest::with('Blanch')->get();
```

Not sure why you are using left joins when you are not selecting any columns from these table nor applying any filter or aggregation.